# "Cheat" or "cheater"?

Tags: word-usage

In Australia, most people of my age call someone who cheats in any form (sport, relationships, whatever) a "cheat", not a "cheater".

In American English, I only hear the latter ever.

Why? Is there a difference or nuance that I'm missing?

Comment: Similarly in Britain,  it is "cheat"; one rarely hears "cheater".

Comment: Just don't call someone [*The* Cheat](http://www.hrwiki.org/wiki/The_Cheat)

Answer (score 4):

Both forms are used in American English, although "cheater" may be more common. There is no difference in meaning when referring to a person. Here are some examples of "cheat" in this sense:

> Meg thought what a no-good, lying cheat he had turned out to be.
> <sub>[Into the Fury](https://books.google.com/books?id=vGwDCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA361&lpg=PA361&dq=%22Meg+thought+what+a+no-good,+lying+cheat+he+had+turned+out+to+be%22.)</sub>

<!>

> Whether Brady is branded as a cheat for conspiring to gain a competitive advantage or as a victim of Commissioner Roger Goodell’s broad authority on discipline matters, he has adamantly maintained his innocence, denying that he was, as the investigation said, “generally aware” of a plot to deflate footballs before the 2015 A.F.C. championship game.
> <sub>[Patriots’ Tom Brady, After Weeks of Simmering, Returns to Roast the Browns](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/10/10/sports/football/tom-brady-new-england-patriots-cleveland-browns.html)</sub>

<!>

> Even if a parishioner was a cantankerous bingo cheat who ruined midnight Mass by accidentally setting the Christmas tree on fire, the Catholic community must honor his or her wish to be buried in a Catholic cemetery.
> <sub>[Where can Catholics be buried?](https://www.uscatholic.org/articles/201410/where-can-catholics-be-buried-29527)</sub>

These are only a couple of examples. You can find more by searching [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) for `cheat_nn*` (which finds "cheat" when it is a noun) and scanning the results for the occasions where it refers to people.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there certainly is a nuance.

I'd use *cheat* for someone who habitually cheats, whose nature it is to cheat, or who has repeatedly cheated me. "I have known him for a **cheat**."

OTOH, I prefer to call someone the *cheater* in the context of a specific incident of cheating. "So, who was the **cheater**?"

This [Quizlet flash-card](https://quizlet.com/101187889/formal-synthetic-and-material-norms-flash-cards/) here thinks otherwise, though.

> One must cheat multiple times to be a cheater. … Murderer is a person that murders, when it is said that one should not Murder it is a synthetic norm because one MUST be a murderer to murder  … One can cheat without being a cheater